# How can a ClearCase directory version be determined for a given file version?

Tags: clearcase

Because ClearCase updates directory version numbers when files inside are created, our config-spec generating script is failing (details omitted).

So, as an example, given a file such as "/proj/src/scripts/build.sh@@/main/branch42/3", how can we determine the latest version of the scripts directory that contains that version of the build.sh file.

Note: we're looking for a unix command-line solution that can be scripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `ls /proj/src/scripts@@/main/branch42/*/build.sh/main/branch42/3` you should get a list of all versions of the `scripts` directory that contain version `.../3` of `build.sh`. Then you should be able to pick out the latest of those.

The above is probably not a fool proof approach, so you might try something more like

```
cleartool find /proj/src/scripts --allversions --nonvisible -name build.sh -version 'brtype(branch42) && version(3)' -print
```

(I no longer have a clearcase environment to test in, so the above is from memory and is not an accurate command)

Comment: The "ls" command does the job.  We'd seen something similar but were confused by the output -- multiple file versions over all directory versions.  Now that we've figured out how that happens, we're all good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to:

- set a label on the right version of the build.sh script and its directory (you can move that label when needed)
- have a second dynamic view always configured to select that label

```
    element * SCRIPT_LABEL
    element /proj/... .../branch42/LATEST
```

That way, you simply read the information you need from that second dynamic view.

Comment: Thanks.  Labeling is under strict change control (gov), but the 2nd dynamic view is a cleaner solution than updating the awkward script. I've filed a request for it.